# How to solve C6386 warning?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, warnings

I'm writing a simple code to read systemized data from .txt file, and got warning "C6386: Buffer overrun while writing to 'points': the writable size is 'num*8' bytes, but '16' bytes might be written". How to solve it in my case ? Code attached.

```cpp
struct point {
    int x, y;
};

void main()
{
    fstream file;
    point* points;
    int num, 
        i = 0;

    file.open("C:\\Users\\Den\\Desktop\\file.txt", fstream::in);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        cout << "No file found\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        file >> num;
        points = new point[num];
    }

    while (file >> num) {
        points[i].x = num;   // <- here
        file >> num;
        points[i].y = num;
        i++;
    }

    file.close();
}
```

Comment: What is `i`? What is `num` (the first value)? I mean their values for your input file.txt ;)

Comment: How sure are you that there aren't more than the first read into `num`  entries in the file? Be a good time to edit the question to add a small sample input that triggers the error so we can see what's up.

Comment: i - just an iterator, num - integer

Comment: user4581301, there is not an error, just warning message in visual studio. Program is working fine, as I want, but I just wonder why there is such an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a warning but it is giving good advice. What if the file contains more than `num` items? The warning is telling you that should make sure you don't write past the end of the array. Specifically:

*This warning indicates that the writable extent of the specified buffer might be smaller than the index used to write to it. This can cause buffer overrun.* [[msdn]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/c6386?view=vs-2019)

This code does not produce the warning (VS2019):

```
int x, y;
while (i < num && (file >> x >> y)) {
    points[i].x = x;
    points[i].y = y;
    i++;
}
```

There is still more error checking to add. What if `file >> num;` fails? What if `num` is negative ? What if `points = new point[num];` fails (returns `nullptr`)?

---

Updated with full error checking:

```
struct point {
    int x, y;
};

void main()
{
    ifstream file("C:\\Users\\Den\\Desktop\\file.txt");
    if (!file) {
        cerr << "No file found\n";
        exit(-1);
    }

    int num;
    if (!(file >> num) || num <= 0) {
        cerr << "invalid num\n";
        exit(-1);
    }
    point *points = new point[num];
    if (!points) {
        cerr << "new failed\n";
        exit(-1);
    }
    int num_items = 0;
    while (num_items < num && file >> points[num_items].x >> points[num_items].y) {
        num_items++;
    }
    // Do some work here
    delete [] points;
}
```

In the future, consider using `std::vector` over raw array.

Comment: As I said, the data is systemized and generated, so I don't really need many checks, but I'll consider in future fact that reading can fail, so thank you again.

Comment: Thanks, I have the same issue, looks like it just give you some failed possibility scenario, but, if you add more conditional check before assignment, it won't show.

Comment: @BoxVery Not sure what you mean. I updated with full error checking.